# select * from Win32_OperatingSystem throwing exception

Tags: c#, wpf, system.management

I hace a WPF application and I'm am using the following to obtain the OS details of my PC:

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher win32OperatingSystem = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem"))
{
     foreach (ManagementObject obj in win32OperatingSystem.Get())
     {
         _operatingSystem = obj["Caption"].ToString();
         _osArchitecture = obj["OSArchitecture"].ToString();
         break;
     }
}
```

WhenI step into this line:

**ManagementObject obj in win32OperatingSystem.Get())**

I get the following exception:

*Invalid Query.*

WHat is wrong here??

Comment: Did you get any valid reason why the error is thrown?

Comment: I get an `invalid class` exception on some machines but not on all

Answer (score 1):

WMI classes have a namespace, you didn't specify one.  Use [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) to get your queries correct, it generates the C# code for you and you can run it right from the tool to check the results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the properties of the [`Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Environment_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class (instead of `ManagementObjectSearcher`) to get those details.

```
string _operatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion.VersionString;
```

Comment: THis gives me "Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1" but I'm running Windows 7 which is what I want to display to the user.

Comment: At least for 8.1(+) Environment.OSVersion.VersionString doesn't necessary display the running OS. (Rather its influenced by the C# application's manifest)

Comment: could you justify your suggestion?